# python: update mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update a mysql table with variable names. Below is the code that is not working for me:

```
import mysql.connector
    conn= mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        passwd=password,
        database=database
    )

    cur = conn.cursor()

 cur.execute("update player_list set country = '%s', region = '%s',name = '%s' where id = %s "
             % (country, region,name, id))
```

Running the "cur execute" line returns the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

The ID column is an integer if it has any importance.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? (your link didnt return anything)

Comment: It's a [bad idea](https://xkcd.com/327/) to use string substitution to add values to an SQL statement. You should be passing the values separately to `execute`.

Comment: It's a bad idea because if that string contains quotes or other special characters, it will break your query, or worse, let people [execute whatever code they want](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any code here how you've created your cursor, but looks like you need to specify buffered mode for your sql class to read.
Please, refer to official documentation and change your code to use buffer=True while creating your cursor and use it afterwards.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql = "update player_list set country = '%s', region = '%s',name = '%s' where id = %s" % (country, region,name, id)
        cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

and add buffered = True into your conn like

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect([...], buffered = True)
```

Comment: btw I recommend you to use PyMysql instead of mysql